# БЕМ Правильно ли я дал классы по бем?

Tags: html, бэм

Правильно ли я дал классы по бем? Если нет, поправьте пожалуйста.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="first-header">
    <div class="first-header-inner">
      <nav class="first-header-inner-first-nav">
        <ul class="first-header-inner-first-nav-ul">
          <li class="first-header-inner-first-nav__li"></li>
          <li class="first-header-inner-first-nav__li"></li>
          <li class="first-header-inner-first-nav__li"></li>
          <li class="first-header-inner-first-nav__li"></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ИМХО не стоит давать такие прям длинные названия (я когда начинал изучать БЭМ тоже по началу фанатски именовал, но потом это превратилось в кашу), я бы сделал что-то подобное:

Модификатор должен указывать на принадлежность или какое-то состояние.

```css
.header__first .nav__first .nav-ul {
  background-color: red;
}

.header__first .nav__first .nav-li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header header__first">
    <div class="header-inner">
      <nav class="nav nav__first">
        <ul class="nav-ul">
          <li class="nav-li"></li>
          <li class="nav-li"></li>
          <li class="nav-li"></li>
          <li class="nav-li"></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: `header` - блок, `header__first` - элемент, т.е. у вас блок = элемент, это не очень хорошо)

Comment: @meine, нет, блок-элемент__модификатор

Comment: почитайте документацию, пожалуйста

Comment: @meine, принципы БЭМ не меняются, если использовать - вместо __ и __ вместо _. Как разделять блоки, элементы и модификаторы может решать сам разработчик. Я бы Вам рекомендовал обратить внимание на этот раздел (https://ru.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/#%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), если Вы ссылаетесь на документацию.